# Angular Highcharts hideNoData not working dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts

I have trouble getting the hideNoData() and showNoData() to work with the official highcharts-angular component (https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular).

Here is a basic example in stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-highcharts-zvkcys?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

This is a simplified version. In my real project I'm fetching data async, and while loading I show my custom (not the one highcharts provides) loading indicator. So initially I want to turn off the no Data Message but once the result comes back, depending on the result I might need to show the no Data Message.

I already tried using the `[(update)]="updateFlag"` on the chart component to trigger a change after calling `hideNoData()` but with no effect. Same goes for `update()`, `reflow()` or `redraw()`.

I even manually called `detectChanges` to force a digest cycle but also with no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I found the solution. Apparently Highcharts cannot handle it in the same digest cycle.  if i call

```
setTimeout(() => {
    chart.hideNoData();
});
```

It works and is correctly hidden. However now it briefly flashes in the beginning, the solution to that is disabling the automatic message completely. In the chart options add following:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load(): void {
            this.hasData = (): boolean => {
                return true;
            };
        },
    },
},
```

Comment: Glad you've found your solution. If you actually never want the `no data message` to show, maybe there is a better route. Check my edit.

Comment: I want it to show, just not initially but rather dynamically depending on different async requests. Thanks for your addition, didn't know that option

Answer (score 2):

With Highcharts, I find it's important for my components to know the charts reference, you can use the supplied `Output` callback, in `highcharts-chart` to do this. In your component you can do:

```
public callback = this.chartCallback.bind(this);
```

Where `chartCallback` is:

```
public chartCallback(chart: Highcharts.Chart)
{
    this.chart = chart;
}
```

HTML will look like:

```
<highcharts-chart [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [options]="options
                  [callbackFunction]="callback">
</highcharts-chart>
```

This allows us to grab the actual reference of the Highchart object, and use it like:

```
public hideNoData(): void
{
    this.chart.hideNoData();
}
```

But ofcourse, once you have the reference to the chart, you can use it freely within the component.

See [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-highcharts-tyihxe?file=app/app.component.ts) for a full working example.

---

Additionally, if you never want the `no data message` to show. Then this might be your best route:

```
this.options = {
    title : { text : 'simple chart' },
    series: [{
        data: [],
    }],
    noData: null
};
```

Comment: i'm already working on the reference and getting the instance of the highchart object. i will update my answer